How do antennas catch the correct radio signal in the air?
Radio signals come to antennas from certain directions. How does the antenna process of receiving the signal in the air work? How does a certain antenna receive this electromagnetic field as the radio signal travels through the air? Why does that antenna receive it and not another conductor? Also, doesn't an electromagnetic signal get lost when it is received by other antennas before it reaches the target antenna?
Specifically, I ask the following.
How is the signal from an antenna directed towards the target?
How is the signal coming to the target antenna pulled towards itself by the antenna?

This question is similar to: How can current flow through an open wire (like a dipole antenna)?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Possibly relevant:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/35412/4993

This could be helpful in aiding your understanding, although not directly related: https://youtu.be/GVYEVhZ-BaE

Welcome to Close Exchange!

I think this question shouldn't have been closed. Some of the answers here are even better than the other question, and contain more information!

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/427490/247642


How do antennas catch the correct radio signal in the air?

They don't. They catch all the signals that are within their operating band (which is generally much wider than a single broadcasting channel).
Then the receiver electronics that they are connected to selects an individual channel to receive, amplify, and demodulate or decode.

How does a certain antenna receive this electromagnetic field as the radio signal travels through the air?

It depends on the geometry of the antenna. An antenna made up of a long straight wire works by the electric field component of the EM wave driving conductors in the antenna back and forth. An antenna made up of a loop of wire works by the magnetic field component of the EM wave inducing an emf around the loop. Other shapes are more complicated but typically work by reflecting the EM field from a large area onto a smaller antenna that works like one of the above.

Why does that antenna receive it and not another conductor?

Other conductors can. That's why electrical engineers spend a lot of time worrying about electromagnetic compatibility and electromagnetic compliance.

Also, doesn't an electromagnetic signal get lost when it is received by other antennas before it reaches the target antenna?

Typically antennas aren't that efficient at extracting power from the EM wave. Also, even if they did completely absorb the power that reached them, the wave would refract around them after a few wavelengths and be available for a second antenna to receive.

How is the signal from an antenna directed towards the target?

This is a very complicated question, but it basically involves designing the transmitting antenna so that radiation from it interferes constructively in the direction you want to send a signal and destructively in the directions you don't want to send the signal.

How is the signal coming to the target antenna pulled towards itself by the antenna?

It isn't. The receiving antenna just receives the (usually tiny) portion of the transmitted signal that happens to reach its actual surface.

What drives a radio signal to reach the surface? Why does it reach the surface specifically where the target is?

The signal doesn't go specifically to where the receiver is. The broadcast signal goes to a wide area, and if people want to receive it they can put their receiver antennas anywhere that the signal is going.

But signal is transmitted through the air How can it be received by an antenna on the ground? How exactly does the process of receiving this signal through the air work? @The Photon

@Ahmet, typically you extend your antenna above the ground into the air. Burying it in the ground is usually ineffective. (but also google the image effect which allows the ground to be used as a reflector that doubles the effective length of an antenna)

@Ahmet I suggest reading an amateur radio handbook for some practical information on antenna design and operation. You may be able to find an older edition (even one from the 1960's would help you) online for free, or if you're in the US find one at your local public library.

Maybe there is a misunderstanding. When I said "surface" I meant the actual surface of the antenna. The boundary between the physical structure of the antenna and the air around it. I didn't mean the ground that the antenna is standing on.

"Typically antennas aren't that efficient at extracting power from the EM wave." Antenna engineers spend most of their time to make their antennas as efficient as physically possible given the external geometrical and costs limitations put on them.

@hyportnex, but often one of the constraints is cost. Leading to basic dipoles and loops still being common despite the availability of parabolic reflectors and other more efficient designs. The antennas OP is probably most familiar with (attached to their TV or radio) are not very efficient.

Why does that antenna receive it and not another conductor?  I had a company that made solar powered traffic signals. The large solar panels, wrapped in a metal frame, became perfect antennas for electromagnetic interference that caused havoc to our circuit boards until we physically separated the charging circuits from the traffic signal circuits.

The broadcast signal is not directed in most cases. It goes in all directions.  That is why millions of people can listen to the same radio station.
Broadcasts are made on narrow frequency bands, and it is the job of the receiver to be tuned to a certain frequency and filter the desired signal from the general cacophony of radio signals that exists in the ambient environment.

Although this is technically correct, most of the broadcast patterns you cited do transmit in all directions – but some more strongly than others. My main goal was to correct the OP's mistaken idea of a point to point transmission.  And I can adjust the wording to cover the intent which was the entire receiving apparatus

To add to The Photon's answer:
A clever antenna design can actually behave significantly "larger" than its physical cross-section for signal capture, as follows. We can place a "dummy antenna" that is not connected to anything a short distance in front of the actual antenna. The incoming radio wave strikes the dummy element first and wastes some time interacting with it. That portion of the plane wave front is now slightly phase-delayed relative to the rest of the wave and the wave then refracts (bends in) slightly around the dummy element- so more of the plane wave strikes the "active" antenna behind it.
We can add more dummy elements like this in front of the active element to diffract more and more of the incoming plane wave into the active element, yielding an antenna that now consists of a long horizontal beam (bristling with little antenna elements sticking out from its sides) that you point at the broadcasting antenna. This is the principle behind old-school rooftop TV antennas from the pre-cable era and is called the Yagi-Uda design after its Japanese inventors.
